# Filtering by dates in Google App Engine's Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having some issues trying to filter a set of objets by their date. Right now I can get all of a
user's transactions like this:

```
> t = Transaction.all().filter("client_email =", "some_email").filter("application_id =", "foo").fetch(100)
> len(t)
# => 4
```

Now, if I want to set up some date filters:

```
> min = datetime.datetime(2009, 2, 3, 0, 0)
> max = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 4, 0, 0)

> len(Transaction.gql("WHERE client_email =:1 AND date >:2 AND date <=:3 AND application_id =:4", 
                      "some_email", min, max, "foo").fetch(100))
# => 2
```

I know all those transactions have a date < max && > min:

```
> map(lambda x: x.date, t)
# => [datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 2, 22, 43, 51), datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 5, 2, 5, 24), datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 7, 16, 51, 5), datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 7, 16, 6, 53)]
```

Yup, all those transactions were made in October 2009. I filtered them in Python just to confirm
that it was right:

```
> trans = filter(lambda x: x.date < max and x.date >= min, t)
> len(trans)
# => 4
```

So yes, they all have the correct dates but due to something in my query the results don't match the
expected results, any idea of what might be wrong in the query?

Comment: Perhaps the client_email or the application_id aren't what you think they are? Perhaps you mean `<` and `>=` (as you have in your later code) and not `<=` and `>` (as you have in the query)?

Comment: @Jonathan: The ordering is different in both examples but you can see that those dates should still fall inside that range.
WRT the properties: You can see that filtering only by application_id and client_email returns 4 results, not 2, so the issue is on the dates.

Comment: Are you showing all of the gql in the non-working example? Is there any detail at all that's different? Is there a sort?

Comment: That's the exact query I'm doing right now, the only difference is that I hid the user's email and the application_id. Every other detail is copied/pasted from the application.

Comment: Well, just for fun, add an `order by` clause with the date to see if that helps.

Comment: After adding and index and an order("-date") I got the same 2 results back (instead of four). I'm deleting the indexes and rebuilding to see if it helps with anything.

Comment: @maciej Can't be sure, this happened years ago :)

Comment: Did you perhaps, in the past, have the date properties marked as `indexed=False`? If so, you need to re-put those entities in order to have their values indexed.

Comment: @NickJohnson I think you provided an alternate solution on the GAE mailing list when this originally became a problem. It's been too long and I cna' thonestly remember what ended up happening.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the query date info compliant with [App Engine GQL syntax](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax)?. E.g syntax:

```
DATETIME(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
DATETIME('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
DATE(year, month, day)
DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')
TIME(hour, minute, second)
TIME('HH:MM:SS')
```

Try running the following GQL:

```
"WHERE client_email =:1 AND date > DATE(:2) AND date <= DATE(:3) AND application_id =:4", "some_email", "2009-02-03", "2009-11-04", "foo"
```

Comment: This will make no difference at all, except to complicate things.